# Calling ofstream.close doesn't release the file

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

After executing code like this:

```
{
    ofstream ofs("file.txt", ios::app);
    ofs << "Output" << endl;
    ofs.close();

    Sleep(100); //just in case
    bool opened = ofs.is_open(); //always false
} //ofs out of scope
```

I would expect file.txt to be completely free, but if I open it with notepad I cant edit the file because it's owned by process until my program exits. How do I make the file accessible?

Comment: `close` is doing the right thing, `ofs` is no longer open...

Comment: use Process Explorer(Windows, `lsof` in Linux) to check whether the process is using the file.

Comment: Is your `ofs` object scope global? If not, what happens to the file handle once `ofs` goes out of scope?

Comment: @txtechhelp Its local and even after its out of scope file still not released

Comment: ofstream::close internally calls filebuf::close which sets failbit in case of failure. So you could check the failbit by calling of.rdstate(). reference: [ofstream::close](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/close/) and [ios::rdstate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdstate/)